# When state of widget is created

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two `tabA`, `tabB` and these are switched by user tapping.

What I want to do is

1. At first `tabA` opens.
2. `tabB` text changes depending on `tabA` state.
3. user opens `tabB`,there comes changed text.

My basic idea is getting the `tabB` state via object key.

However there is a problem,

Before opening tabB, state of tabB is not created.

These are my source code `tabA` is `playerPage`, `tabB` is `settingPage`

```
class _MainFrameState extends State<MainFrame>{
  void _onItemTapped(int index) => setState(() => _selectedIndex = index );
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  Widget settingPage = Text("");
  Widget playerPage = Text("");

  GlobalKey<_PlayerPageState> _playerPageKey = new GlobalKey<_PlayerPageState>();
  GlobalKey<_SettingPageState> _settingPageKey = new GlobalKey<_SettingPageState>();
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    print("Main Frame init state");
    super.initState();
    playerPage = PlayerPage(key:_playerPageKey);
    settingPage = SettingPage(key:_settingPageKey);


  }
  function whenSomethingChanged(){ //this is called by push button or some user action,so initState() is already called.
      print(playerPage.currentState!) // it has state and operatable.
      print(settingPage.currentState!)  // I want to change the tabB text but it returns null.

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Main Frame build");
    
    List<Widget> _pages = [
      playerPage,
      settingPage
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      
      appBar: EmptyAppBar(),
      body:Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
        child:Center(child:_pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex),)),
        
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: Color(0xffC03410),
        unselectedItemColor: Color(0xffE96D2F),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffF7BF51),
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.play_circle),
            label: 'Player',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'Setting',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I can tell that when first build is called `PlayerPage` is created but `SettingPage` is not.

However I want to control the SettinPage , before it show.

What is the solution for this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't tell what kind of state of TabA you want to show on TabB, I will assume it's a String and wrote this. There's a lot of ways of doing what you want to achieve, this is just one of them.

Step 1: Pass the value of PlayerPage state to SettingPage like this:

```
class SettingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SettingPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;

  @override
  _SettingPageState createState() => _SettingPageState();
}

class _SettingPageState extends State<SettingPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text(widget.text));
  }
}
```

Step 2: Let's assume state you want to show on SettingPage is from TextField. Maybe a player name. Then you'll need to pass that textField value to MainFrame() widget whenever it changes.

```
class PlayerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlayerPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.onTextChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Function(String) onTextChanged;

  @override
  _PlayerPagetate createState() => _PlayerPagetate();
}

class _PlayerPagetate extends State<PlayerPage> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: TextField(
        controller: _controller,
        onChanged: (value) {
          widget.onTextChanged(value);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Step 3: On MainFrame widget, now you get playerName into _playerName variable from PlayerPlage and pass it into SettingPage like this. Whenever the value changes _playerName will change too:

```
class _MainFrameState extends State<MainFrame> {
  void _onItemTapped(int index) => setState(() => _selectedIndex = index);
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  String _playerName = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Main Frame build");

    List<Widget> _pages = [
      PlayerPage(onTextChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _playerName = value;
        });
      }),
      SettingPage(text: _playerName)
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      // rest of the codes are same.
    )
```

Comment: I see thank you for detail of steps. I understood the system, and I will decide to make every pages in advance and keep it in mainframe.

Answer (score 0):

Since your settingPage is not in the tree, you can't really access its state because it was not created.

Whenever you change your `_selectedIndex` in the code below, either a new settingPage or a playerPage is inflated, so just create it already with the value it depends on, listening to it if necessary.

```
      body:Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
        child:Center(child:_pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex),)),
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I see, I understand it is not created because of not in tree. but how can I create this in advance? Is it possible to create in background?(not shown to user)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are updating the screen based on the users input in page 1 I have included a code where if the text field is empty it will show a message and if it has value that value is displayed in second page

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MainFrame(),
    );
  }
}

class MainFrame extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainFrame({key});

  @override
  State<MainFrame> createState() => _MainFrameState();
}

class _MainFrameState extends State<MainFrame> {
  void _onItemTapped(int index) => setState(() {
        print(playerPageController.text);
        _selectedIndex = index;
      });
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  late TextEditingController playerPageController;

  late Widget settingPage;
  late Widget playerPage;
  late List<Widget> _pages;
  @override
  void initState() {
    playerPageController = TextEditingController();
    print("Main Frame init state");
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    settingPage = Text((playerPageController.text.isEmpty)
        ? "Theres no content here"
        : playerPageController.text);
    playerPage = Center(
        child: TextField(
      controller: playerPageController,
      autofocus: true,
    ));
    _pages = [playerPage, settingPage];
    print("Main Frame build");

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
          child: Center(
            child: _pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
          )),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: Color(0xffC03410),
        unselectedItemColor: Color(0xffE96D2F),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffF7BF51),
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.play_circle),
            label: 'Player',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'Setting',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```